# Exception in boost directory iterator constructor

Tags: c++, boost, boost-filesystem

I'm using the boost filesystem iterator and I have a problem when I try to parse a specific folder. The folder is a remote ftp folder mounted using curòlftpfs as root. The same folder can be mounted also as nfs share. If I run my application on the nfs share the iteration works fine, while if I run it on the ftp share I get the exception. The specific folder that causes the crash is the lost+found folder. It seems the root user has no access to it, but while in the nfs share if I try ls /mnt/remotenfs/lost-found I get a permission denied error, doing ls /mnt/remoteftp/lost+found I get input/output error. While it's obvious that the curlftpfs has some problems, since it should return some kind of permission error, boost should not crash in this case. I tried

```
boost::filesystem3::directory_iterator itr(dir_path);
```

and

```
boost::system::error_code ec;
boost::filesystem3::directory_iterator itr(dir_path, ec);
```

but the result is the same:

```
#0  0x0000003064a329a5 in raise () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x0000003064a34185 in abort () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#2  0x0000003064a2b935 in __assert_fail () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#3  0x000000000043a7b5 in boost::shared_ptr<boost::filesystem3::detail::dir_itr_imp>::operator-> (this=0x7fffd216cf30)
    at /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:414
#4  0x00000000005e89f2 in boost::filesystem3::detail::directory_iterator_increment (it=..., ec=0x0) at libs/filesystem/v3/src/operations.cpp:1947
#5  0x00000000004363af in boost::filesystem3::directory_iterator::increment (this=0x7fffd216cf30) at /usr/include/boost/filesystem/v3/operations.hpp:630
#6  0x00000000005e8810 in boost::filesystem3::detail::directory_iterator_construct (it=..., p=..., ec=0x7fffd216cf40)
    at libs/filesystem/v3/src/operations.cpp:1918
#7  0x000000000054a120 in boost::filesystem3::directory_iterator::directory_iterator (this=0x7fffd216cf30, p=..., ec=...)
    at /usr/include/boost/filesystem/v3/operations.hpp:598
```

Is there any additional control that I can do in order to avoid the crash? Ingoring the folder would be the desider behavior, but I cannot find any boost filesystem check function that allows me to ignore it!
I'm using boost version 1.49. Please note that it is impossibile at the time to move to a newer boost version.

Answer (score 0):

put your boost code in try and catch statements.

```
try { //code here}
catch(boost::filesystem::filesystem_error &ex){std::cout << ex.what() << "\n";}
```

Comment: As you can see from the stack trace, it's not a c++ exception, but an assert failure